# Wordpress - Check if page is the main page

Tags: wordpress

How can I check if the page is a home page?

I have this pages, Home, News.
In Reading Settings I set:
Front page: - Home
Posts page: - News

When I check

```
var_dump(is_front_page());
var_dump(is_home());
```

Home Page and News Page has the same values

> boolean false
>
> boolean true

But I need to separate them and know the Front page.

Comment: Do you have a static homepage? Then try is_page('Home'). Have a read on the correct usage here: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-homepage-conditional/

Comment: if(is_front_page()({ echo  do this   } else {  do  this }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

make sure `wp_reset_query();`  is set before the conditional tag.

**Why using wp_reset_query:**

word press always keeps the original, unaltered query intact. So, to get back that where all the conditional tags works we have to use the `wp_reset_query`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the index.php home page and the designated home page

So is necessary to definition it individually in both cases
'is_home or is_front_page'  not  'is_front_page and is_front_page'

this can help you:

```
if(is_front_page() || is_home()){
    //do sothing
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I modified it

Answer (score 0):

`is_front_page()` When the front of the site is displayed, whether it is posts or a Page. Returns true when the main blog page is being displayed and the 'Settings > Reading ->Front page displays' is set to "Your latest posts", or when 'Settings > Reading ->Front page displays' is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_front_page()({ echo do this } else { do this }
```

Comment: is_front_page is the same in Home page and News.

Comment: if you want to chage the  front page go to setting  reading then select the static page and select the  front page  fron ther eand save

Comment: I did I set Front page: - Home, Posts page: - News

Comment: When I set In Reading Settings: Front page: - Home, 
Posts page: - News, I couldn't separate them. How to know that this is Home page, or blog page, or other pages. 
http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-homepage-conditional/ this doesn't work property in my case.

Comment: make the different template  and page  for  home and news and set accordingly